# Quantization Noise Power

Tags: adc

[image]

[Marcel Pelgrom, Analog-to-Digital Conversion]

Hi,

I'm a bit confused on how the author here derives the quantization power from the sawtooth wave. How exactly is he integrating using values from the y-axis? I attempted it by splitting a single sawtooth period into two triangles and calculating area, however my answer is different:
[image]

Comment: Can you show your integral?

Answer (score 3):

The Y axis in that plot is amplitude.  The book integrates the amplitude squared because it is calculating the noise power (remember, power is proportional to amplitude squared).

You took the absolute value of amplitude, but didn't square it, so you now have the average absolute energy of the error.